# Nested directive inside template is placed at the top

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having issues with an angularjs directive I'm attempting to make.

The main directive is called tableu, which has a tableu-heading and a tableu-body, both of which are inside a table like so:

```
<table>
    <tableu-heading headings='data.format'>
    </tableu-heading>
    <tableu-body data='data'>
    </tableu-body>
</table>
```

The issue is, that in chrome and firefox, (but not in IE8 for some reason) is that the resulting code that is inserted when I envoke the directive is formatted strangly. I end up with;

```
<tableu>
    <tableu-heading>
    </tableu-heading>
    <tableu-body>
    <tableu-body>
    <table>
    </table>
</tableu>
```

So that my nested directives are placed inline with table. I've tried a few permutations with transclude thinking that might be the problem but I can't seem to resolve the issue.

My directive code is thus:

```
angular.module('air.directives.tableu',[])

.directive('tableu', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    scope: {
        data: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: 'template/tableu/tableu.html'
  };
})

.directive('tableuHeading',function() {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        headings: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'template/tableu/tableu-heading.html',
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {


        return function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        }
    }
  };
})

.directive('tableuBody',function() {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    transclude: true,
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: 'template/tableu/tableu-body.html',
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {


        return function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        }
    }
  };
})
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated - I can't but think the solution is probably obvious.

Comment: Can you please use jsbin.com, plnkr.co, or jsfiddle.net to create a working example of the problem?

Comment: I think this is just how the browsers work (i.e., this is not an Angular issue).  If you put your `tableu` template directly into the HTML and then look at the "Elements" tab in Chrome, you'll see the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Rajcok seems to be correct. The solution for me was invoke the directives as a class or an attribute instead of an element - which avoids this particular problem.